# Color certain area in TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I've created a very small tikzpicture (see below) and now want to color the area below the intersection of the two curves.

How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) (2,0) };
\draw plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (1.5,0) (2.5,2) (3.5,0) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way for your simple example is to fill a whole rectangle and to `clip` away everything outside your curves.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope} %under the left curve
    \clip plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) (2,0) };
    \path [fill=green!30] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) ;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope} %under the right curve
    \clip plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (1.5,0) (2.5,2) (3.5,0) };
    \path [fill=blue!30] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) ;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope} %under both curves
    \clip plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) (2,0) };
    \clip plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (1.5,0) (2.5,2) (3.5,0) };
    \path [fill=red!30] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) ;
  \end{scope}
  % and now, we draw the curves :
  \draw plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) (2,0) };
  \draw plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (1.5,0) (2.5,2) (3.5,0) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```